# How to grey out Views. Specifically an EditText?

Tags: android, view, android-edittext

Hey guy's 
First of all thanks for reading this.
I'm having trouble to find a way to change my EditText when I loose focus to it.
I would like it to be greyed out when this happens, but I don't want it to be disabled because the user can touch it and edit the text later.

Anyone?

Greetings!

Comment: Greyed out implies that it can not be touched or used.  I would reconsider your strategy.

Comment: hmm, ok, but is it possible? I'm following a designer's layout so I must implement the way he specified...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [set different colors to the text](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextColor%28int%29) based on an [OnFocusChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener.html)

Another option is to set a style in xml. See this question for details: [Android: change style when focused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572868/android-change-style-when-focused)

To change the opacity, use [setAlpha](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAlpha%28float%29). In this answer I show it how to do it in an animation: [Two questions about custom app ui's and AlphaAnimation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085912/two-questions-about-custom-app-uis-and-alphaanimation/6086125#6086125)

Comment: For next time, that should really be another question. See the updated answer for setting the opacity.

Comment: the problem is that I don't have access to setAlpha through my editText.. how can I access a method from the superclass (view) through the subclass (edittext)?? sorry for those newbie questions it's my first android project!

Comment: All derived classes have access to the public methods of the superclass. I would suggest you to read this before continuing: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: Looking back to this after a few years it's nostalgic hahahaha I've come a long way

Comment:  for setAlpha

Comment: “setAlpha” did the job. Thanks!