# Android Make EditText enabled when it is touched

Tags: android

This is kind of a chicken and egg problem.  For touch event to be caught, I need the EditText to be enabled.  But its touching the EditBox that is required to be the enabler.  How can this be done.  How can I catch a touch event on an non-enabled view and enable it based on that geature?  Thanks

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve, As there can be another way around we can suggest...Please describe your logic behind enabling only "onTouch" Thnks

Answer (score 0):

You are answering yourself. You need it to be enabled to respond to touch events.

Check the answer here: [How to grey out Views. Specifically an EditText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6100203/how-to-grey-out-views-specifically-an-edittext/6100258#6100258) for an alternative (changing the color/transparency with focus)